En symfony 5 ¿Es posible Crear rutas leyendo un fichero X(json/xml/yaml) etc externo al proyecto de symfony?
A ver la situación es la siguiente:
Para evitar realizar despliegues a producción cada vez que se requiere añadir una entrada o ruta nueva para determinada página, quisiera poder agregar esas reglas a un json o yaml externo de tal manera que podría simplemente actualizar el fichero con la regla y url nueva y esta se cargaría al gestor de rutas para que cuando entre la ruta se ejecute.
Normalmente estas rutas irían siempre al mismo controller:action asi que solo seria cargar las reglas para que exista la ruta.
Podría ser algo parecido a lo que hace wordpress que tiene rutas acorde como se van creando posts, por fechas por titulo etc; pero estas rutas las tenemos que definir. Esto también podría ser aplicado por ejemplo a una base de datos donde tenga almacenado las reglas de las rutas a agregar por ejemplo.
¿ Esto seria muy rebuscado ?
¿ Es mejor simplemente incorporar las rutas directamente y desplegar ?
Esto es por evitar despliegues no previsto a producción simplemente por agregar unas rutas nuevas. No se si es posible o muy rebuscado o liado, ya que seguramente tendría que agregar listener y tocar configuraciones del kernel y mas cosas para que esto funcione sin mencionar que seguramente este fichero estaría dado por una api a la cual tendría que invocar ya que no estaría disponible para una lectura local. Pero si existe la posibilidad y es complicado podría exponer el caso para evitar esta locura y dar razones para no hacerlo.^.^

en programacion todo se puede.

te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

no comprendo que quieres decir con esto: Esto es por evitar despliegues no previsto a producción simplemente por agregar unas rutas nuevas

creo que algo que se controla desde la administracion del proyecto no deberia controlarce desde el codigo ... y viceversa ...

Ciertamente lo mismo digo, que por agregar simples rutas no veo males de hacer despliegues, pero son cosas que se ponen a discutir, los jefes. Aun así yo voy un poco en contra de tener que inventar rutas dinámicamente rutas que sean externas al proyecto, solo por no hacer despliegues.

Pues Hurgando mas en la red he encontrado mas información la respecto, en la documentación de symfony he encontrado el RoutingLoader
y un Bundle (de symfony-cmf/routing-bundle) que podría funcionar a la mayoría de los casos. Es probable que terminemos haciendo implementación del custom_route_loader; pero almenos ya tengo mas clara la posible solución a la alternativa que se nos pide.
